# How can I work around this composer error? (not available in a stable-enough version)

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to install PHP-Rocker, and the installation composer.json is:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require" : {
        "rocker/server": "1.2.6"
    }
}
```

When i run composer install, i get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for rocker/server 1.2.6 -> satisfiable by rocker/server[1.2.6].
    - rocker/server 1.2.6 requires jlogsdon/cli dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

How can i workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rocker/server` package is no longer being maintained. The reason you are getting that error is because the `jlogsdon/cli` package has been deprecated. The author has removed the code from the master branch. Since `rocker/server` relies on that master branch, it cannot be installed.

I would recommend that you **do not use this package**. Use something that is better maintained and that does not rely on development versions of other packages (dev-master versions).

If you really need to use PHP-Rocker, you need to fork it and replace the `jlogsdon/cli` dependency with its successor `wp-cli/php-cli-tools`.